# Send notification on google calendar event delete

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I want to send notification when deleting an event :

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("myp12filepath", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = Scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
initializer.ApplicationName = ApplicationName;
var service1 = new CalendarService(initializer);

var googleCalendarEvent = service1.Events.Delete("calendarId", "eventId").Execute();
```

The delete function does not accept a third parameter (indicating whether or not to send a notification) as mentioned in this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete#try-it) (there is no c# example)

So is there a way to send email notifications after deleting an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of delete request and assign notification as true. See below.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("myp12filepath", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = Scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
initializer.ApplicationName = ApplicationName;
var service1 = new CalendarService(initializer);

EventsResource.DeleteRequest delReq = service1.Events.Delete("calendarId", "eventId");
delReq.SendNotifications = true;
var googleCalendarEvent = delReq.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to set `sendNotifications` to `true` if you want to send notifications about the deletion of the event as also mentioned in your given [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete#try-it). And in addition to that, for a user to receive notifications, user's notification setting should also be checked for each of the calendars as mentioned in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/xnBC_tdFh0c) and also as given [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en).

Listed below are the steps to turn notification on or off:

> You can choose whether to have notifications for events, and whether you want to get notifications over email or in your browser.
>
> 1. Open [Google Calendar](https://calendar.google.com/) on your computer.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings (gear icon) **> Settings**.
> 3. At the top of the page, click the **Calendars** tab.
> 4. Next to your calendar's name, click **Edit notifications**.
> 5. Click **Add notification** or edit an existing notification.
> 6. At the bottom of the page, click **Save**.
>
> **Note**: To get notifications on your computer, you need to have Google Calendar open in your browser.

Lastly, since there is not much sample for C#, the [.NET client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) might help.

Comment: The problem is that the delete method doesn't accept a third parameter (sendNotifications)